# Post request to server

Tags: javascript, browser, firebug, lotus-notes, xpages

I know that it is very funny and foolish. But tell me that

Is their anyway to write the javascript code in script tab of Firebug, That will invoke serverside action.

**

> Simply tell, Can I write the serverside javacsript code in Firebug
>   script tab?

**

Comment: eval() === 'evil'; // Yes you can

Comment: Please can you give an simple example, For me it is throwing syntax error.

Comment: first you need to master eval(); See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP Then follow Sven't advice

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot execute SSJS code in Firebug script tab. But you could use the "executeOnServer"-Function to invoke a serverside action.

See here for more details:

http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC

**EDIT:**

If you have added this CSJS-function to your XPage, you can invoke a event on the server by executing this code in the firebug console

```
executeOnServer('eventhandler1a');
```

This would invoke event `eventhandler1a` on the server.

Hope this helps
Sven

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Medusa project on OpenNTF. It is discontinued now, but I think peek into sources could be helpful to you.

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Medusa

Comment: It would be cool if it would be picked up again, but Nathan is swamped and a debugger is around the corner.